# Webpack style-loader / css-loader: url() path resolution not working

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, webpack-style-loader, css-loader

There are a few SO posts about `style-loader` and `css-loader`, but despite this I have not been able to find a solution to my problem.

In short summary, when I `@import` `css` files in other `css` files, and the imported `css` contains `url()`s with relative paths, the paths are not resolved correctly.

Basically, the error message shows that Webpack ends up thinking the `url()` paths in the imported css are relative to `src` (main entry point), rather than being relative to the `css` file it it is imported into:

```
// css-one.scss
@import "./assets/open-iconic-master/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.css";

// open-iconic-bootstrap.css
@font-face {
    src: url('../fonts/open-iconic.eot');
}
```

**Error:**

> ERROR in ./src/main.scss
>   (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--5-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--5-3!./src/main.scss)
>
> Module not found: **Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/open-iconic.eot'** in
>   **'C:\Users\...\src'**
>   **@ ./src/main.scss**
>   (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--5-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--5-3!./src/main.scss) 7:106-141 7:172-207  @ ./src/main.scss  @ ./src/index.js

**What I Have Tried:**

- I have tried to use the `convertToAbsoluteUrls` flag in style-loader
- I have tried to turn off all source maps ([mentioned in style-loader docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/style-loader))

**My Webpack Config File (loaders are at the bottom):**

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack'); // for webpack built-in plugins
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
// const WriteFilePlugin = require('write-file-webpack-plugin');
// const ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
// const InlineManifestWebpackPlugin = require('inline-manifest-webpack-plugin');

// const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

const PATHS = {
  // when using __dirname, resolve and join gives same result,
  // because __dirname is absolute path to directory of this file.
  // OK to use no slashes,
  // both resolve and join adds platform-specific separators by default
  src: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
  dist: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  build: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
  test: path.resolve(__dirname, 'test')
};

const NAMES = {
  // JS FILES
  index: 'index',
  print: 'print',
  // Chrome Extension Development
  popup: 'popup',
  options: 'options',
  background: 'background',
  contentScript: 'contentScript',

  // FOLDERS
  assets: 'assets',
  utilities: 'utilities',
  images: 'images',
  fonts: 'fonts',
  include: 'include'
};

const FILE_PATHS = {
  // JS
  indexJs: `${path.join(PATHS.src, NAMES.index)}.js`,
  printJs: `${path.join(PATHS.src, NAMES.print)}.js`,
  // Chrome Extension Development
  popupJs: `${path.join(PATHS.src, NAMES.popup)}.js`,
  optionsJs: `${path.join(PATHS.src, NAMES.options)}.js`,
  backgroundJs: `${path.join(PATHS.src, NAMES.background)}.js`,
  contentScriptJs: `${path.join(
    PATHS.src,
    NAMES.include,
    NAMES.contentScript
  )}.js`,

  // HTML
  indexHtml: `${path.join(PATHS.src, NAMES.index)}.html`,
  printHtml: `${path.join(PATHS.src, NAMES.print)}.html`,
  // Chrome Extension Development
  popupHtml: `${path.join(PATHS.src, NAMES.popup)}.html`,
  optionsHtml: `${path.join(PATHS.src, NAMES.options)}.html`,
  backgroundHtml: `${path.join(PATHS.src, NAMES.background)}.html`
};

// Third-party (vendor) libraries to include
// const VENDORS = ['react', 'bootstrap', 'lodash', 'jQuery']; // Relative paths to node_modules

// Note: These are relative
const ASSETS = {
  images: path.join(NAMES.assets, NAMES.images),
  fonts: path.join(NAMES.assets, NAMES.fonts)
};

// CleanWebpackPlugin config
const pathsToClean = [PATHS.dist, PATHS.build];
const cleanOptions = {
  root: __dirname,
  exclude: ['shared.js'],
  verbose: true,
  dry: false
};

// CopyWebpackPlugin config
const copyPattern = [
  // {
  // from: NAMES.assets,
  // to: NAMES.assets
  // },
  // {
  // from: path.join(NAMES.include, 'contentScript.css')
  // },
  // {
  // from: 'manifest.json',
  // transform(content, copyPath) {
  // // generates the manifest file using the package.json informations
  // return Buffer.from(
  // JSON.stringify({
  // ...JSON.parse(content.toString())
  // // description: env.npm_package_description,
  // // version: env.npm_package_version
  // })
  // );
  // }
  // }
];
const copyOptions = {
  // ignore: ['*.js'],
  context: PATHS.src
};

module.exports = (env = {}) => {
  // webpack injects env variable, into webpack config.
  // perfect to check for production.
  // remember to specify --env.production in command
  // (if in production mode).
  const isProduction = env.production === true;

  return {
    entry: {
      index: FILE_PATHS.indexJs

      // Chrome Extension Development
      // popup: FILE_PATHS.popupJs,
      // contentScript: FILE_PATHS.contentScriptJs
      // options: FILE_PATHS.optionsJs,
      // background: FILE_PATHS.backgroundJs,

      // vendor: VENDORS
    },
    mode: isProduction ? 'production' : 'development',
    devtool: isProduction ? 'source-map' : 'inline-source-map',
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all'
      }
    },
    output: {
      filename: isProduction ? '[name].[chunkhash:8].js' : '[name].js',
      // chunkFilename determine name of non-entry chunk files,
      // for example dynamic imports in the app
      chunkFilename: isProduction ? '[name].[chunkhash:8].js' : '[name].js',
      path: PATHS.dist
    },
    plugins: [
      // new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
      // filename: '[file].map',
      // exclude: ['vendor', 'runtime']
      // }),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        // specifies environment variable for dependencies.
        // does not apply to browser runtime environment
        // (process.env is provisioned by Node)
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': isProduction ?
          JSON.stringify('production') :
          JSON.stringify('development')
      }),
      // new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
      new CleanWebpackPlugin(pathsToClean, cleanOptions),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
        // both options are optional
        // does not work with Hot Module Replacement (HMR)
        // allows HMR in development (will only use this plugin in production)
        filename: isProduction ? '[name].[contenthash].css' : '[name].css',
        chunkFilename: isProduction ? '[id].[contenthash].css' : '[id].css'
      }),
      new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),
      isProduction ?
      new UglifyJSPlugin({
        cache: true,
        parallel: true,
        sourceMap: true // set to true if you want JS source maps
      }) :
      () => {},
      new CopyWebpackPlugin(copyPattern, copyOptions),
      // new WriteFilePlugin(),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: FILE_PATHS.indexHtml,
        filename: `${NAMES.index}.html`
      })
      // new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      // template: FILE_PATHS.popupHtml,
      // filename: `${NAMES.popup}.html`,
      // excludeChunks: [NAMES.contentScript]
      // In dev mode, chunks excluded vendor chunk (which holds CSS).
      // Above check fixes it.
      // }),
      // new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      // filename: `${NAMES.contentScript}.html`,
      // excludeChunks: [NAMES.popup, 'runtime'] // Runtime only needed in one HTML
      // }),
      // new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      // template: FILE_PATHS.optionsHtml,
      // filename: `${NAMES.options}.html`,
      // chunks: isProduction ? [NAMES.options] : ''
      // }),
      // new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      // template: FILE_PATHS.backgroundHtml,
      // filename: `${NAMES.background}.html`,
      // chunks: isProduction ? [NAMES.background] : ''
      // }),
      // no need for CSS minimization here <-- Done by PostCSS (cssnano)
      // new InlineManifestWebpackPlugin(),
      // new ManifestPlugin({fileName: 'webpack-manifest.json'}),
    ],
    module: {
      rules: [{
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
            }
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.s?[ac]ss$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: [
            isProduction ?
            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader :
            {
              // creates style nodes from JS strings
              loader: 'style-loader',
              options: {
                sourceMap: true,
                convertToAbsoluteUrls: true
              }
            },
            {
              // CSS to CommonJS (resolves CSS imports into exported CSS strings)
              loader: 'css-loader',
              options: {
                sourceMap: true,
                importLoaders: 2
              }
            },
            {
              loader: 'postcss-loader',
              options: {
                config: {
                  ctx: {
                    cssnext: {},
                    cssnano: {},
                    autoprefixer: {}
                  }
                },
                sourceMap: true
              }
            },
            {
              // compiles Sass to CSS
              loader: 'sass-loader',
              options: {
                sourceMap: true
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
          use: [{
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[hash:4].[ext]',
              outputPath: ASSETS.images
            }
          }]
        },
        {
          test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
          use: [{
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[hash:4].[ext]',
              outputPath: ASSETS.fonts
            }
          }]
        },
        {
          test: /\.(csv|tsv)$/,
          use: ['csv-loader']
        },
        {
          test: /\.xml$/,
          use: ['xml-loader']
        },
        {
          test: /\.(html)$/,
          use: {
            loader: 'html-loader',
            options: {
              interpolate: 'require',
              minimize: true
            }
          }
        }
        // {
        // test: /\.tsx?$/,
        // exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        // use: 'ts-loader'
        // }
      ]
    },
    devServer: {
      // contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
      contentBase: PATHS.dist,
      compress: false,
      port: 8080,
      open: false
    }
  };
};
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem myself. In case it could help others in the future, please find the solution below.

---

1. First of all, if you are using both `postcss-loader` with the `postcss-import` plugin, AND `css-loader`, turn off / delete the `postcss-import` plugin. You do not need more than one tool that resolves `@import` rules. This is not really a problem if the order of loaders is correct, but you might as well remove it.
2. In the [sass-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader) docs, you can [read the following](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#problems-with-url):

> Since Sass/libsass does not provide url rewriting, all linked assets
>   must be relative to the output.
>
> - If you're just generating CSS without passing it to the css-loader, it must be relative to your web root.
> - If you pass the generated CSS on to the css-loader, all urls must be relative to the entry-file (e.g. main.scss).
>
> More likely you will be disrupted by this second issue. It is natural to expect relative references to be resolved against the .scss file in which they are specified (like in regular .css files). Thankfully there are two solutions to this problem:
>
> - Add the missing url rewriting using the resolve-url-loader. Place it before the sass-loader in the loader chain.
> - Library authors usually provide a variable to modify the asset path. bootstrap-sass for example has an $icon-font-path. Check out this working bootstrap example.

I decided to follow bullet two, and add in `resolve-url-loader` above `sass-loader` in the *Webpack* config. It now works as expected.

**My final Webpack config (for now) looks like this:**

```
    {
      test: /\.s?[ac]ss$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: [
        isProduction
          ? MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
          : {
              // creates style nodes from JS strings
              loader: 'style-loader',
              options: {
                sourceMap: true,
                // convertToAbsoluteUrls: true
              }
            },
        {
          // CSS to CommonJS (resolves CSS imports into exported CSS strings)
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            sourceMap: true,
            importLoaders: 2
            // url: false,
            // import: false
          }
        },
        {
          loader: 'postcss-loader',
          options: {
            config: {
              ctx: {
                cssnext: {},
                cssnano: {},
                autoprefixer: {}
              }
            },
            sourceMap: true
          }
        },
        {
          loader: 'resolve-url-loader',
          options: {
            attempts: 1,
            sourceMap: true
          }
        },
        {
          // compiles Sass to CSS
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          options: { sourceMap: true }
        }
      ]
    },
```

**Side Notes**

1. I noticed that source map paths under "no domain" in Chrome's debugger are repeated. If anyone figures out why, please do share
2. Remember to include the below side effects in `package.json`, so tree shaking, which happens in production mode, does not delete the extracted css

   "sideEffects": [
       "*.css",
       "*.scss"
     ],

Answer (score 25):

it took me around 5 days of work to understand how this webpack mess works. I have to be honest I can say that this is one of those things that I really do not understand why they are "defacto" tools of the moment. I can't understand how difficult it can be just to make the config files work as it should, in gulp took me 1 hour to do the same.

My problem was that all the url() rules (including fonts and images) were being loaded by css-loader as [object Module], and they where exported by file-loader but never loaded, so if I added ?url=false to the css-loader it never copied the files and export them.  I have to say this was a totally PITA, but I got it working, and I hope it works for somebody else in the world, this was made with webpack 4.

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const ImageminPlugin = require('imagemin-webpack-plugin').default;
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    mode: "development",
    module: {
        rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: { presets: ["@babel/env"] }
        },
        {
            test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
            use: [
            {
                loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
                options: {
                    mozjpeg: {
                        progressive: true,
                        quality: 65
                    },

                    optipng: {
                        enabled: false,
                    },
                    pngquant: {
                        quality: [0.65, 0.90],
                        speed: 4
                    },
                    gifsicle: {
                        interlaced: false,
                    },

                    webp: {
                        quality: 75
                    },
                }
            },
            {
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options:{
                    name: '[name].[ext]',
                    outputPath: 'images/',
                    publicPath: 'images/'
                }
            },
            'url-loader?limit=100000'
            ],
        },
        {
            test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            use: [
            {
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '[name].[ext]',
                    outputPath: 'fonts/'
                }
            }
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
            use: [
            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            { loader: 'css-loader?url=false'},
            { loader: 'sass-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } }
            ],
        },
        ]
    },
    resolve: { extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx"] },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/"),
        publicPath: "",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist/"),
        port: 3000,
        publicPath: "http://localhost:3000/dist/",
        hotOnly: true
    },
    plugins: [ new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
    new CopyPlugin([{ from: 'src/images/', to: 'images/' }]),
    new CopyPlugin([{ from: 'src/fonts/', to: 'fonts/' }]),
    new ImageminPlugin({ test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        hash: true,
        template: './src/index.html',
            filename: './index.html' //relative to root of the application
        }),
    ]
};
```

Comment: I am totally agree with you. It was heartpain to migrate from Gulp to Webpack.

Comment: I have the exact same problem that my files are never copied...
What are the crucial parts of your solution? I am trying to get this to work with webpack 5.

Comment: It seems that I could not get it to work with `options: { url: false }`. I had to rewrite certain `url` links...

Comment: @Merc would be cool you share ur solution so others can base on it

Comment: Well this did not resolve my problem anyway. By using option above, I would kinda cloak the problem because these files just were not processed anymore by webpack.
I am still trying to find a proper solution but this existing project is killing me :S.

and: the `url: false` solution is just one of the solutions proposed in this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63662916/1121268 and is already described.

Comment: I can't believe this little thing did the trick for me! Thank you! FYI: My setup is `{ Webpack: 1.15.0, css-loader: 0.23.1 }` and inside _webpack.config.js_ I had `module:loaders:loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader")`. The problem was that paths like _url(./assets/..._ inside a custom npm package in node_modules were not being resolved.

Comment: it is my pleasure @pkpapani

Answer (score 18):

You can turn off processing of `url()` rules, btw. I have no idea, why this is a default behavior.

```
{
  loader: 'css-loader',
  options: {
    ...
    url: false,
  }
},
```

Comment: This was only working for me once I restarted webpack.

Comment: Found this helpful when using Elixir with Phoenix Framework, since it comes bundled with webpack and css-loader by default. Ran into filepath issues after upgrading css-loader and simplest solution was to turn off processing as outlined above.

Answer (score 1):

In webpack 5, you should refrain from using `raw-loader` and `file-loader`, instead use `asset/source` and `asset/resource`.

```
  {
    test: /\.txt$/,
    type: 'asset/source',
  },
  {
    test: /\.png$/,
    type: 'asset/resource',
  },
```

You can read more about assets on: https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/. It's described how for Webpack 4 and earlier you should use `file-loader`, and for Webpack5 and later you should use asset modules.

Answer (score 1):

1. remove file-loader or reconfigure to not process css files as css-loader handles url()
2. expreriment with relative paths it can be relative to entry file or to css file where url() is used

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is struggling with this using Webpack 5 and is trying to upgrade from css-loader 5 to css-loader 6, you might need to check [this issue](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/1337) where the poster has a similar problem to the OP:

> With css-loader 5.2.7 the images in the input stylus were embedded as data-
> URL in the output CSS. With css-loader 6, the images are instead moved
> to the output directory.

See Notes [here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/releases/tag/v6.0.0) for how to upgrade to css-loader 6 - the salient points are:

> using ~ is deprecated when the esModules option is enabled ... and can
> be removed from your code

and

> file-loader and url-loader are deprecated, please migrate on asset
> modules, since v6 css-loader is generating new URL(...) syntax, it
> enables by default built-in assets modules, i.e. type: 'asset' for all
> url()

---

I've therefore done the following:

1. removed any '~' in my .scss files

i.e.

```
$font-path: "~/src/fonts" !default;
```

becomes

```
$font-path: "/src/fonts" !default;
```

2. I've also removed the 'file-loader' module completely.

All NPM packages are now up to date and URLs in CSS are working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

IE is not compatible with new URL()

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that webpack 5 changed everything with "Asset modules" apparently and broke file-loader.

Official docs explain it well: https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/

TL;DR you can fix it by adding `type: 'javascript/auto'` to the rule/loader

```
            {
                test: /\.(eot|ttf|woff2?)($|\?)/i,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '[name]-[sha1:hash:hex:10].[ext]',
                    esModule: false,
                },
                type: 'javascript/auto'
            },
```