# post-css not finding paths from node_modules

Tags: css, webpack, sass

I currently have a Angular project which I am looking to purge the css using purgecss.

I have got everything working but when I import node_modules it struggles as it cannot find the paths which are located in the node_modules folder.

I have the current `app.scss` file

```
@import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/scss/fontawesome";
@import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/scss/regular";

@import "./_buttons";
```

The buttons class is actually called `_buttons.scss` but for some reason the postcss does not pick this up so I have to define the `_` although I know it can be imported without.

So that is the first issue which I would like to fix if possible but the second is that when importing font awesome, it finds the font awesome package but it cannot find the file `variables` after I looked into the package I can see that there is no relative path and it is just `variables`. As this is a package is there a way to mitigate this issue within webpack to stop this from happening and the build from failing?

Here is my `webpack.config.js`

```
const purgecss = require("@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss");

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: "postcss-loader",
        options: {
          modules: true,
          importLoaders: 1,
          ident: "postcss",
          syntax: "postcss-scss",
          plugins: () => [
            require("postcss-import"),
            require("autoprefixer"),
            purgecss({
              content: ["./**/*.html"],
              whitelistPatterns: [/^cdk-|mat-/],
              defaultExtractor: content =>
                content.match(/[\w-/:]+(?<!:)/g) || []
            })
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

I've tried setting `importLoaders: 1` which didn't seem to make a difference at all.

How can I get postcss to run from the files root directory? Even without the `./` which is used in the fontawesome package and also the postcss recognising the `scss` file without having to explicit prefix everything with `_`

Edit (font awesome error):

fontawesome.scss

```
@import 'variables';
@import 'mixins';
@import 'core';
@import 'larger';
@import 'fixed-width';
@import 'list';
@import 'bordered-pulled';
@import 'animated';
@import 'rotated-flipped';
@import 'stacked';
@import 'icons';
@import 'screen-reader';
```

> Error: Failed to find 'variables'

Comment: Hey, I'm having the same issue. Did you sort it out in the end?

Comment: @BrunoBruzzano same here have you found something?

Comment: @Spawnrad I think I gave up in the end :-/

Comment: check my solution here please https://stackoverflow.com/a/65505377/2221804

Answer (score 3):

Well, maybe this could help you, in the webpack.config.js you should add, specifically in purgeCss -> content, the diferents paths.

```
content: [
    "./node_modules/name_package/**/**/*.{css,scss}"
]
```

I had the same issue using NextJS in production.

Answer (score 2):

After a day of wasting time, finally, i found the souloution. There is a `postcss` plugin to do it for us!

First, install it using npm as dev dependency:

```
npm i postcss-url -D
```

Now you must update your `webpack.config.js` to use `postcss-url`. Just add `postcss-url` directly after `postcss-import`

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me, when I removed the
 `require("postcss-import")` from the webpack.config.js file. It took me 1 day to resolve it. Found the explanation here: [Webpack style-loader / css-loader: url() path resolution not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52219401/9527725)